# CSS: align the ul under the input

Tags: css

How can i make the "Megan fox" ul li under the input field

http://jsfiddle.net/Ne8zy/3/

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the absolute position of `.suggestionsBox_tags` and then add `margin:0 auto;` to center the div.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ne8zy/8/

Answer (score 0):

First off what's making this complicated is the text-align:center and margin:auto property in your body selector.

To fix your problem you can:

1) Set the width of your li and/or ul elements to be the same width as your textbox

or

2) Remove text-align:center and margin:auto from the body and set these only where you need them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin: 0 auto;` to center the element.

Don't use `text-align: center` on any element that contains block elements, Internet Explorer doesn't handle that correctly.

Set both `margin` and `padding` on body, different browsers have different default values for those.

I removed the absolute positioning on the element containing the list, and centered it. And some other cleanup.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ne8zy/7/